# Input tipo correo separado por comas,

Tags: php, html5, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un `input` que es tipo `email`, 
en el cual necesito tener la posibilidad de colocar varios correos,  `a@hotmail.com, b@hotmail.com`,  sería de esa manera al poner `n` cantidad de correos para que el método de reenvío se puedan agregar varios correos.

El método puede o no venir con uno o mas correos, este es el método de reenviar correo que esta hecho en `laravel`.

```
public function reenvio(Request $request){
      $subject = $request->input('subject');
      $e_mail = $request->input('emails');  
      $estipulo = $request->input('editor1');
      $files = $request->input('link');
      Mail::send('emails.reenvia',array(
           'e_mail'   =>  $e_mail,
           'subject' => $subject,
           'estipulo'    =>  $estipulo,
           'files'  =>  $files, 
      ),
      function($msj)use($e_mail,$estipulo,$subject,$files){
          $msj->subject($subject);
          $msj->to($e_mail);
          if($files) {
            foreach ($files as $attachment) {
              $msj->attach(public_path('/storage/boletines/').$attachment, [
                          'as' => $attachment,
                          'mime' => 'application/pdf',
              ]);    
            }
          }
      });
   return Redirect::to('/Admin/reportes/create');
  } 
}
```

La vista sería esta es en la cual se mete los correos por medio del `input`, como puedo modificar el método para que separe por comas y lo tome como un correo:

```
@section('menu2')
   <div id="menu2" style="display: block; width: 90%; height: 110%; opacity: 1; float: left;">  
<br>
<form class="form-group" method="POST"  name="formNombre" action="/renviar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      @csrf
      <!-- 'link','id','emails','firma','texto','titulo' -->
     <div class="clientes">
        <input type="hidden" name="func" value="ActualizarCliente">
        <input type="hidden" id="cliente-id" name="cliente-id" value="62">
        <div class="titulo">
          Renvio de Correo
        </div>
        <label class="lavelstyle">Correos:</label>
          @foreach($history as $his)
          <input type="text" class="inputEmailstyle" placeholder="Correos" size="50" name="emails" value="{{$his->emails}}">
          @endforeach
          <br>
          <br><br>
          <!--<label style="position: absolute; left: 15%" >Asunto Correo:</label>--->
          @foreach($history as $his)
          <label class="labelstyleasuntos">Asunto:  </label>
          <input type="text" class="inputAsuntostyle" name="subject" value="RE:: {{$his->titulo}}" placeholder="Titulo de correo" required="required" size="50">
          @endforeach
          <button type="submit"  class="btnAgregar buttonstylereenviar" value="enviar correo">reenviar correo</button>


          <div class="typePlantillaStyle">
            <br>
            @foreach($history as $his)
            <b>Tipo de Plantilla:</b>{{$his->texto}}<input type="text" hidden="hidden" name="" value="{{$his->texto}}">
            @endforeach
          </div>
          <div class="checkboxpositionstyle">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                       <textarea  class="ckeditor checkboxpositionstyle"  name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                             @foreach($history as $his)
                             {{$his->firma}}
                              @endforeach
                        </textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>
          </div> 
            <br><br>
            <div class="filegetstyle">
            @foreach($history as $his)
            <label >Archivo adjunto:</label>{{$his->link}}
            <input type="text" hidden="hidden" value="{{$his->link}}" name="link[]">
            @endforeach
            </div>

            </div>

       </div>
</div>
</form>
<!--SWAL() alerts-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ActivadorEditor(){
    $('#editor1').wysihtml5();
  };
  ActivadorEditor();
</script>
</div>
@endsection
```

Si me pudieran ayudar con esto, actualmente el puede enviar correos pero no los envía `n` cantidad solo uno por uno lo cual no me sirve. ya que tendría que tener la capacidad de poder realizar esto con un montón de correos.

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el problema o qué es lo que no funciona aquí.

Comment: ok en el input pongo dos correos  ejemplo uno,dos  al momento de enviar eso no se envía no reconoce que son dos correos distintos y entonces nunca envia el correo

Comment: ¿el campo en el formulario es `emails`?

Comment: Si, es el campo donde dice emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta respuesta está lejos de ser perfecta, pero te orienta sobre cómo resolverlo:

Asumiendo que el contenido del mensaje siempre sean una o más direcciones de correo electrónico separadas por coma (,), lo primero que debes hacer una vez has recibido los datos en el controlador (previamente debiste haber realizado una validación) es separar las direcciones, lo cual puedes hacer con explode():

```
$e_mail = $request->input('emails'); 

$emails = explode(",", $e_mail);
```

Posteriormente puedes pasar ese array directamente al Mailable:

```
Mail::to($emails)->send(new MyEmail());
```

Revisa la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#sending-mail

---

Veo algunas cosas confusas en tu código: la forma como intentas enviar el correo, la falta de validación y un foreach en la vista que rodea el campo de correos. Por favor revisa dichas secciones.